# Conditional probability working backwards in a probability tree

Tags: probability

I currently have this question..

*A survey was conducted that found 72% of respondents liked the new motorway. Of all respondents, 65% intend to drive more. Suppose that 81% of those who like the new motorway intend to drive more.*

I get rather confused with how the 65% and 81% intertwine. I assume I'm working backwards to find out the percentage of those who don't like the new motorway but intend to drive more.

Let l = like, d = drive..

*pr(l) = 0.72  ,  pr(l') = 0.28*

Would I be right in claiming that *pr(d) = 0.65* therefore *pr(d | l) = 0.65/0.72* ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have left out the question that was asked. The question presumably they goes "what is the probability that $\dots$. I can guess what it is from what you tried to do, but it is best to have the full question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $n$ be the number of respondents. You know that $0.72n$ like the new motorway, and that $81$% of those $0.72n$ intend to drive more. Thus, $0.81\cdot0.72n=0.5832n$ like the new motorway **and** intend to drive more. You also know that $0.65n$ intend to drive more. Thus, the number who intend to drive more but do **not** like the new motorway must be ... ? (Of course once you have the number, you can express it as a percentage easily enough.)

Comment: Would that be 0.65 * 0.28 = 0.182n?

Comment: @Androx: No, it's much simpler than that. $0.65n$ intend to drive more; $0.5832n$ intend to drive more **and** like the new motorway. How should you combine these two numbers to find out how many intend to drive more and do **not** like the new motorway? You need no other numbers here.

Comment: 0.65 / 0.5832 = 1.1145?

Comment: @Androx: You're not thinking: $1.1145n$ would be **more people than responded to the survey**! Let's try some concrete numbers. Suppose that $n=10000$; then $6500$ intend to drive more, and $5832$ intend to drive more and also like the new motorway. How many of the $6500$ who intend to drive more do **not** like the new motorway?

Comment: Yeah I apologise, my knowledge on this topic is severely lacking. Thanks for the taking the time out to assist me with this, I really appreciate it. Alright, is it as simple as going 0.65 - 0.5832?

Comment: @Androx: Almost: you just have to include the factor of $n$, making it $0.65n-0.5832n=0.0668n$. Recall that $n$ was the number of respondents, so this is $6.68$% of them. (You're welcome.)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks once again, nice to finally understand it.

Comment: @Androx: You're welcome; glad to help!